# accessing selected radio button value inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I write the code. Where I am trying to write a form which is having a long list of radio button content inside 'iframe' like below:

```
<form name="iframeform" method="POST" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/run">
    <tr>
            <td><iframe id="macList" src="http://localhost/macinfo" style="width:1000px;height:160px">
            </iframe></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="macaddr" value="">
            <td><input type="submit" name="macselect" value="Continue" id="stdbtn" onclick="getIframeContent()"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

'iframe' is pointing to macinfo page is having code like below:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type=radio name=mac value=E8:B7:48:7B:C0:4A>abc.example.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type=radio name=mac value=00:17:08:5A:81:CF>xyz.cisco.com</td>
</tr>
....
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I write "getIframeContent()" function to fetch the value of selected radio button? please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short. To access iframe `document` use `.contentWindow.document`, i.e.:

```
document.getElementById('macList').contentWindow.document
```

And an example code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getIframeContent(){
         var myIFrame = document.getElementById('macList');
         var myIFDoc  = myIFrame.contentWindow.document;
         var myRadios = myIFDoc.getElementsByName("mac");

         var checkedItemValue = "";
         for(var i=0; i<myRadios.length; i++) {
            if (myRadios[i].checked) {
               checkedItemValue = myRadios[i].value;
            }
         }
         if (checkedItemValue) {
            alert(checkedItemValue);
         } else {alert('Select address');}
      }
    </script>
  </head>
<body>

  <iframe id="macList" src="..." 
      style="width:600px;height:160px">
  </iframe>

  <input type="submit" onclick="getIframeContent();">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the array of `mac` using `document.getElementsByName` and loop over them:

```
var allRadios = document.getElementsByName("mac");
var checkedItem; 
for(var i=0; i<allRadios.length; i++) {
     if (allRadios[i].checked) {
          checkedItem = allRadios[i];
          alert('Found checked radio button');
     }
 }
```

You could then pass `checkedItem` to your `getIframeContent` function.

**Edit**

You could share the `checkedItem` variable across two pages by using `window`

```
window.checkedItem = allRadios[i];
```

Comment: But I think the code you have written above, I need to write in 'macinfo' html file. Then how can I fetch 'checkItem' variable value in function getIframeContent(), which I will write in the same html file, where iframe is calling 'macinfo' file?

Comment: @user1552407 you could store it in window.checkedItem which would work across multiple pages.